# Read a string with spaces into MATLAB from a file

Tags: matlab, file-io, scanf

In my text file I have several lines of input in the following format

```
Arun 3 4.0 Text
```

where Text can be a string of several words separated by spaces.

I want to read this into MATLAB such that I get a 4xn matrix, where Arun, 3, 4.0, Text should be the four fields for each entry in the Result Matrix.

I tried using `fscanf`, but `fscanf` assumes that the different terms are space separated.

So in the above example, if Text was say "Hello World", then `fscanf` returns 5 items

```
[Arun, 3, 4.0, Hello, World]
```

but what I want is something like

```
[Arun, 3, 4.0, Hello World]
```

So, how do I achieve this in Hadoop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use textscan function (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
C = textscan(fileID, '%s %d %f %[^\n]')
```